# Bizarre RealTek (RTL8723BE) wifi driver saga on 19.04

Tags: wireless, 19.04, realtek

I have a really strange issue with an HP laptop that's using the cursed RealTek integrated wifi chip, RTL8723BE in my case.

On Ubuntu 17.x and 18.04 the default driver works fine. After I performed a dist-upgrade from 18.04 to  19.04 the driver loads but the network list is empty. 
Running `iwlist wlp19s0 scan` just produces an empty list. If I reboot into 18.04 off the live cd, I'm able to connect normally.

I have installed the latest driver from this [github repo](https://github.com/lwfinger/rtlwifi_new.git):

... loaded both natively into the kernel (make install) and also tried them installing the via DKMS. Both methods load (notably tainting the kernel, but that's another story).

Per many excellent responses here, I have also attempted to hard-code the antenna in etc/modprobe.d file from 0-4 which has had no effect, including giving it some power-off time to reset. The driver shows as being loaded, and nmcli sees the card but shows it as disconnected.

full output of the wifi troubleshooting script here on the site can be found via [this link](https://pastebin.com/urfmDrzZ):

I can manually `modprobe -r` the driver and add it back in with no errors. The one suspect thing I see is that in the interfaces there is a new device called p2p-dev in addition to the regular wifi interface.

```
$:~/scratch$ iwconfig 
lo        no wireless extensions.

enp7s0    no wireless extensions.

wlp19s0   IEEE 802.11  ESSID:off/any  
          Mode:Managed  Access Point: Not-Associated   Tx-Power=20 dBm   
          Retry short limit:7   RTS thr=2347 B   Fragment thr:off
          Power Management:on


$ nmcli dev status
DEVICE           TYPE      STATE         CONNECTION 
wlp19s0          wifi      disconnected  --         
p2p-dev-wlp19s0  wifi-p2p  disconnected  --         
enp7s0           ethernet  unavailable   --         
lo               loopback  unmanaged     --
```

Big thanks in advance for any ideas or suggestions. 
I was really hoping that I wouldn't have to nuke my disk and start-over on 18.04.

cheers, 
Twister

Comment: On Ubuntu 19.04 you don't need drivers from git. Remove them.

Comment: Thanks - but those didn't work the first time. I tried setting the antenna from 1-4 first using the default driver to no effect before downloading the 3rd party src ones. 

Is it possible to load the older 18.04 driver off the live-cd whilst still using a 5.0+ kernel?

Comment: There is no antenna 3 or 4. That it is some fantasy of a manual writer. Threre are options 0,1,2 there. You need first to find out what is the problem before starting to install all kind of compatible or not drivers. It is hard to debug now.

Comment: I know it's not the hardware, antenna, nor location. live-cd loads the driver and network list on the first crack, which appears to default the antenna to zero. 

0,1,2 didn't work with the default kernel driver off 5.0.0-28

Comment: All your question is unclear. You can't `dist-upgrade` from 18.04 to 19.04, etc. I suggest doing a fresh install of 18.04.3. It has kernel 5.0 and all should work. The problem is that you have an installed driver that doesn't work. It is very hard to find out what is going on there now.

Comment: Try to boot from 18.04.3 installer in Live mode and see if Wi-Fi works.

Comment: that's how I'm posting here ;)   live-cd driver works instantaneously.  I removed the 3rd party driver and bounced the machine, then modprobe'd the driver to check it's status.  looks identical to live-cd modprobe output, which works. 

The only difference is that the driver is from 5.0.0-23-generic instead of 5.0.0-27-generic, and this p2p-dev device that shows up under nmcli dev status.  This device is not present on the *23-generic version of the driver.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to dig up an ethernet cable and connect to the router, then perform the next dist-upgrade from 19.04 -> 19.10. Happy to report that the default drivers in 5.3.0-10-generic are working great.

I noticed also that the bluetooth driver was failing for this chipset under 19.04, tracing the logs all the way back to the first boot after the upgrade. That problem too has been resolved.

Thanks Pilot6 for the quick suggestions and prior answers on this topic over the years.

Comment: What are you calling `dist-upgrade`?

Comment: Apologies for the lazy term. I mean Distribution Upgrade, invoked by do-release-upgrade in shell. 

Several small things seem to be working better in 19.10. Wayland is not crashing now as it had been under 18.10 while using heavy SPA apps in Chrome. Also, it's a small thing but the RealTek audio drivers are now playing nicely with PulseEffects which is nice. It was not working before.

The AMD Radeon drivers are working by default now, too; they were configured manually before. I was planning on going back to Gnome, but honestly wayland seems much more fluid now with this release.